# React Build Pages/Router/SEO/Sitemap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, sitemap

I have an react web app and it has routes like about,contact etc... When i type "x.x/route" to the browser i get "404 Not Found" but when i click to the link with the  component i get the page and my url = "x.x/route" even i get 404 in manual type

And in sitemap.xml i do not receive the routes

So ... is there anyway to make it optimized for SEO or SITEMAP.XML ?
or how can i make a build with folders

Answer (score 2):

the problem you are presenting is caused because the engine you are using isn't configured properly. I will post Apache and Nginx ones but there are also methods for Express and some others.

For apache this can help:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

For Ngnix add to the site file:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you but i have an godaddy shared linux hosting can i do something with that?

Comment: Do you know which engine are you using? You are probably using apache, do you have a .htaccess file?

Comment: Then just add the code I posted inside the .htaccess file, not sure if you should enable any plugin, it's been a long time I haven't used apache.

Comment: but there is no index.html

Comment: Doesn't your react build (and public folder) have a index.html file in it? Check it well.

Comment: it has but the link doesnt work my website x.x/index.html is gives a blank page

Comment: It probably gives you a blank page because index.html is not configured in react-router, I am not 100% sure but it probably is. Your page at x.x/ loads index.html and react gets as route "/" so it loads "/" but index.html may not be configured but served. (I am not 100% sure rn but I believe it is like this)

Comment: Then just write the code I posted for Apache inside .htaccess

Comment: its not valid the index.html thing shall i delete it?

Comment: Isn't it working? If you haven't tried writing the code do it. If you search "x.x/index.html" may not work because index.html means nothing to react-router as a route. When you write "x.x/" it redirects to index.html "internally" and react-router understands that you are in "/" so it serves "/" content. Correct me if I am wrong but I think I am not.

Comment: @Tsetti ok im deleting index.html thing you are right

Comment: If it works fine for you but I don't remember deleting it. When I search information I see the .htaccess file with index.html. Notify me if it works for you. EDIT: You don't have to update it, look at [this file](https://gist.github.com/alexsasharegan/173878f9d67055bfef63449fa7136042)

Comment: because my htacces file should be rneamed to ".htaccess" and rename acces in the to access